# Simplesamlphp + Azure Active Directory + More sites (infinite loop problem)

Tags: php, azure, azure-active-directory, simplesamlphp

I am new to **simplesamlphp**. I was configuring it to enable single sign-on with **Azure Active Directory** for a PHP website, and I think I managed to do it.

However, now I would like to configure simplesamlphp and Azure Active Directory to use this login for multiple different sites that share the same second-level domain, such as name1.site.com and name2.site.com (these sites on the same server).

The first problem I encountered was with the **response URL**, even though I had set the desired response addresses in Azure Active Directory and also in simplesamlphp's authsources.php file, I keep getting an error that the response URL does not match. It seems to always use the path: .../module.php/saml/sp/saml2-acs.php/mscms-sp. How can I make it use the response address I want?

Here is the code that I put in the authsources.php file:

```
'site2' => [
    'saml:SP',
    'entityID' => 'https://site2.domain.com',
    'idp' => 'https://sts.windows.net/..../',
    'discoURL' => null,
    'AssertionConsumerServiceURL' => 'https://site2.domain.com/login.php',
    'proxymode.passAuthnContextClassRef' => false,
],
```

Are there any other points that I need to check?

Anyway, I temporarily solved the problem by creating the expected path on site 2 as well, but now I'm facing a blocking problem: it enters an **infinite loop**.

After some checks, I discovered that this is probably because the procedure that checks if you are logged in keeps failing and therefore keeps redirecting you to the login page. This might be a cookie problem, as the authentication is on site 1, and site 2 might not be able to read the cookie or session generated by site 1.

I saw that maybe I need to modify the php.ini of site 2 to save cookies with a domain like .domain.com, and I also changed the session cookie name of simplesamlphp to SESSIONID, as well as verified that the storage path was the same, but all this was not enough for now.

Can you guide me to the correct configuration to allow me to use a single installation of simplesamlphp for multiple sites that are on the same server? Thanks!